# Skylanders: how does the autosave work?

Tags: xbox-360, skylanders

My son is playing "Skylanders: Spyro's Adventure" on an Xbox360. Now - I know the game is supposed to autosave each chapter and in some other particular occasions. However, he got to chapter 8, turned off the game and no saved game was there.
I also tried playing a couple of chapters, turning the game off and had everything reset.

Before crying foul, I am quite sure there's something wrong with what I do. But I don't really know what: I play normally for a couple of levels, then press <kbd>Play</kbd> and choose `Exit`.
When I restart the Adventure mode, I only have one option, to start a new adventure.

*How do you make the game save in Skylanders?*

Comment: Saves on the Xbox 360 are generally tied to a profile, are you logging into a profile on the Xbox before you start playing?  Also, have you checked your storage device to see if files are being created by the game?  It's possible that it's full.

Comment: How does the autosave work?  Poorly.  Even when it's working as designed, there's zero capability to save-and-continue-later.

Comment: we're using Wii version. Till yesterday my kid/myself crossed level 20, completing 25%. But today when we started the game, it's starting from Level 1. Not sure what's the issue...! Is there a way to bring back the level 20 again ? If not, is there a way to have the autosave option store the data in the SD card in the Wii...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

You have to sign in with a user, otherwise the game will not save (but will not warn you that it is not saving).

Comment: My son got right to the last level, went on the next day and it had all gone, he's devastated. Now it doesn't seem to be saving as it goes along even though he's logged in on his profile. Help anyone?

Comment: did you install the game on HD?